How to watch video podcasts on Mac?
I would think I should simply launch Podcasts app and click on a podcast episode to play. But I only get audio. Where is the video picture?
Apple Podcasts 1.1.0
MacOS 14.4.1 Sonoma

Can you provide an example of what podcast you are trying to watch?

I tried Joe Rogan, Tesla Daily, PBD, and a few others.

I'm not seeing any video episodes for these podcasts on iPhone or Mac. However, I can find video episodes for 'TED Talks Daily (SD Video)', for example, that play on Mac. My guess is that these podcasts don't have video offerings through Apple Podcasts.

Apple supports video based podcasts.
Your steps appear to be correct.
Here’s one TED Talk video podcast to try and test your setup.

https://podcasters.apple.com/support/3684-video-podcasts

I would reach out to each show you want to watch. You’ll perhaps need their help to understand which episodes they publish or if they haven’t submitted any such content yet.
